# Call controller or view (twig file) from self defined twig extension in smyfony2

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

i've got a problem in symfony2 at the moment and i don't know how i can solve it. 
Within a self defined new twig extension I want to call a controller or or a view (a twig file).

How is the correct way to realize this? Can you help me? I've read many symfony2 internet pages but i didn't found a good programming approach for me.

For better understanding why i want to do something like this, here is an exmaple what is my idea:
I want to source out some html code into an separate view. This new view is embedded in another view by calling the twig extension.

So how can i realize this?

Thanxs for your help.

Comment: i'm not sure i'm following. Woudln't the `include` function of twig suffice?

Comment: or `{{ render(controller('Acme:Soemthing:somethingAction')) }}`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Symfony2, you can inject the `templating` service to your Twig extension and then call the `->render` method.

<kbd>The extension</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace YourPackage\YourBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

class Test_Extension extends \Twig_Extension
{

   protected $templating;

   public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
   {
      $this->templating = $templating;
   }

   public function getFunctions()
   {
      return array(
              new \Twig_SimpleFunction('my_test', array($this->myTest()), array('is_safe' => array('html')))
      );
   }

   public function myTest()
   {
      // do some stuffs
      $data = $this->templating->render("SomeBundle:Directory:file.html.twig");
      // ...
      return $data;
   }

   public function getName()
   {
      return 'test';
   }

}
```

<kbd>services.yml</kbd>

```
# src/YourPackage/YourBUndle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    test.test_extension:
        class: YourPackage\YourBundle\Twig\Extension\TestExtension
        arguments: ['@templating']
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```